# LWC lightning-input Currency

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput, currency, lightning-formatted-number

In Lightning Web Components (LWC) the 'lightning-input' component supports a 'formatter' attribute which has value 'currency' and this displays decimal values with currency formatting, for example:

1.518,71 €

was output by:

```
<lightning-input type="number" step=".01" formatter="currency" value={totalAmount}>
</lightning-input>
```

However, this appears to use the Currency setting on the User's record (in this case 'EUR'). Is there any way this can be formatted as a different currency (e.g. 'CHF' or 'USD') and/or in the currency of the salesforce record from which the field was retrieved?